# Rest API alerts multiple times

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

If loop runs two times it shows alert in success function two times. I have tried with writing a condition inside this success function but that also doesn't work. What needs to be done, so that I get only one alert...

```
for(var k=0;k<array.length;k++)
{

$.ajax({
        url: parts[0]+"_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Certifications')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.CertificationsListItem' }, 
  'Title': data.d.results[k].Title}),
        headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(d) {alert("Items Inserted!"); 
        },
        error: function() {alert("Failed to Insert Items!");}
});
}
```

Comment: are you trying insert multiple items or single item?

Comment: multiple items..

Comment: So why do you need to show the alert only once? Are you trying to show the alert when all items will be inserted?

Comment: yes, wen all items are inserted

Comment: total items are equal to `array.length`?

Comment: I am storing all the ID's of few list items in that array..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31596/discussion-between-atish-dipongkor-and-vikash-kumar).

Comment: What happened to this problem? Did you solve it? @vikashkumar

Comment: I tried many things but at last I put my alert outside the for loop directly saying "values are inserted"

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment, you said that you need to show the alert only once when all items will be inserted. I am assuming that your total items are equal to `array.length`. Try following

```
var numberOfItemInserted = 0;

for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {

    $.ajax({
        url: parts[0] + "_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Certifications')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': {
                'type': 'SP.Data.CertificationsListItem'
            },
            'Title': data.d.results[k].Title
        }),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(d) {

            numberOfItemInserted++;

            if (numberOfItemInserted == array.length) {
                alert("Items Inserted!");
            }

        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Failed to Insert Items!");
        }
    });
}
```

But for this requirement, you can use [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). `doneCallback` will be fired automatically once all items are inserted. So you can try it in the following way.

Define a separate function for adding new item

```
function addNewItem(data, url) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(d) {
            deferred.resolve(d);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Now declare an array to store all promises

```
var addNewItemPromises = [];
```

Now push all promises in the above array

```
array.forEach(function(item) {
    addNewItemPromises.push(addNewItem(someData, "some url"));
});
```

Finally resolve all promises

```
$.when.apply(null, addNewItemPromises).done(function() {
    // this function will be fired once all items are added. call alert here.
    alert("Items Inserted!");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple logic which can be achieved in several ways and I think you might have that logic but you would have confused of that Asynchronous call. but anyways here is another logic to it.

first store the length of array in variable

```
var arrayLength=(array.length-1);

for(var k=0; k < array.length; k++ ) {

$.ajax({

        url: parts[0]+"_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Certifications')/Items",

        type: "POST",

        data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.CertificationsListItem' },  'Title': data.d.results[k].Title}),

        headers: { 

            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",

            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",

            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()

        },

        success: function(d) {if(k == arrayLength){
    alert("Items Inserted!"); }
        },

        error: function() {alert("Failed to Insert Items!");}});}
```

All the best,

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

It's the logic issue. I have edited for code you, Hope it may be help you

```
var showAlert = 0;
for(var k=0;k<array.length;k++)
{

$.ajax({
        url: parts[0]+"_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Certifications')/Items",
        type: "POST",
        data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.CertificationsListItem' }, 
  'Title': data.d.results[k].Title}),
        headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(d) {showAlert = 1},
        error: function() {alert("Failed to Insert Items!");}
});
}
if(showAlert == 1) alert("Items Inserted!");
```